# Context menu for blank space in a listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, contextmenu

I have a simple LinearLayout with ListView inside it (`match_parent` both for width and height). I need a context menu to show up upon a long touch on ANY place in the ListView. First, I called `registerForContextMenu` for the ListView. This makes the context menu show up ONLY if the touch is performed on a list item. Then I called `registerForContextMenu` for the LinearLayout as well, and set it attribute `android:longClickable="true"`. This did not help.

So the question is how can one produce a context menu for a long touch below list items? For example, if we have 1 item in the list view, there is a lot of empty space below the item. Why does it not used for context menu invocation, provided that the list view fills entire parent according to the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that long clicking anywhere on the `ListView` to get a `ContextMenu` it's a normal behavior, one the user will expect(especially in your case, with the user clicking the empty space below the `ListView` and a `ListView` `ContextMenu` would appear).

Anyway, for your example, you can set your `ListView` height attribute to `wrap_content`(If I remember right, this is the recommended value) and then register the `Contextmenu` for the `ListView` and the parent `LinearLayout`(of course you'll have to provide the same code for both).

Comment: This is not a context menu for the list view specifically, but a context menu for the entire screen, so it is perfectly expected by a user to get this context menu anywhere on the screen. Anyway, wrap_conent works ok. Thanks.