# Invoke context menu on long click on ListView without items

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

In my app I have a `ListView`, which I register for context menu.  On long click, I invoke the context menu and from there deal with the item, on which the long click happened.  This works fine. However the user may add items to the list (separate functionality, not related to here) and "add item" is one of the items in the context menu.  This item does not depend on which item I long clicked on.

When the activity starts, there is only one item in the list - and below it the list is empty. When I long-click on the item, the context menu shows up as I want to, however when I long-click in the empty area of the list, nothing happens.  I'm using the pretty much standard code:

```
itemList = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.order_items);
this.registerForContextMenu(itemList);

...

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.order_popup, menu);
    menu.setHeaderTitle(null);
}
```

How can I get the context menu to pop up on long click in the empty space of the list?

Comment: are you sure ListView is occupying whole screen height even though list is empty? I have a doubt for that.

Comment: I've answered something similar here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447676/context-menu-for-blank-space-in-a-listview/10447941#10447941

Comment: @Luksprog I looked at that answer, thanks.  However I don't see how setting ListView's height to wrap_content will achieve the desired results.  When I get a lot of items, they won't fit on screen, so the layout will be messed up.

Comment: The idea was that the menu will not be triggered when long clicking the empty space of a `ListView`. Instead you'll wrap the `ListView` content and place it in a wrapper layout so the long click on the visual empty `ListView`(from the user perspective) will not end up on the `ListView` widget, it will end up on the wrapper layout(showing the same menu). Regarding lots of items messing up the layout, I don't see how that would happen, but then again I don't know you current layout.

Answer (score 0):

The ListView will only take as much space as it needs. I don't think that clicking empty space is very intuitive for a user as well. Why don't you add a menu button, or simple button at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it doesn't solve the problem.  I already have buttons for all the actions, but they are also duplicated in context menu.  The ListView takes the space that I indicated it - otherwise the background colour would have been different.  Therefore the empty space _is_ part of the ListView.

Comment: Ah ok. Have you tried a onLongClickListener for the ListView itself, instead of the items in the list? I don't know if that would work, but perhaps it's worth a try.